# PHP header redirection not working as expected

Tags: php, redirect

I have the following issue. I collect some user input and then write it to a text file using PHP. After this is done I want to redirect to another web page - here www.google.com. I am having difficulty.

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
$IP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"].',';
$logdetails=  $IP.date("F j, Y, g:i a O T");
$stringTimeout = $_POST['_delay'];
$stringData1 = $_POST['userChoices'];
$s = ',';
$postData = $s.$stringTimeout.$s.$stringData1"\n";
fwrite($fh,$logdetails.$postData);
fclose($fh);

header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with?

Comment: what happen? can u please give us some more details?

Comment: Do you output anything before? then it would not work!

Comment: I'm betting some of your code is throwing an error that you're not seeing. Either an error is stopping the script before it finishes, or there's output before the `header`, which would also throw an error. I'd recommend ensuring that your server is not suppressing error messages, which would make debugging much, much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you try your redirect part first in another PHP.
divide and conquer! :)

hey and If that does not work, check your html headers, I remember that I had issues with the html headers trying to use:

header("Location: http://www.google.com");

Answer (score 2):

The header method really suck when it comes to this and the lack of a redirect method is really annoying.

I assume you get the "Headers already set" or "Headers already sent to the browser". In such case use a javascript instead of the header method.

```
//header("Location: http://www.google.com");    
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.href='http://www.google.se'</script>;";
```

Answer (score 1):

I pasted an alternative over the original solution sorry.

Original solution that worked for paul

```
fwrite($fh,$logdetails.$postData,'a');
```

This forces fwrite to amend the file, using the 'w' option will overwrite the file

The alternative I also use for multiple variables is:

```
$write_me = $logdetails.$postData;
fwrite($fh,$write_me);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the space between
`fclose($fh);` and `header("Location: http://www.google.com");`
like in

```
fclose($fh);
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: The new line there is will be ignored, as it's between "<?php" and "?>".  But you raise a good point.  There could be a character before the "<?php" or after the "?>"

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there any error?

It may not be related but it seems to me that you forgot one dot before the last escaped "\n" character:

```
$postData = $s.$stringTimeout.$s.$stringData1."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
ob_end_flush();
exit();
```

after your header() method.

Answer (score 0):

i had also faced this issue many time.
i solved it by putting a die(); on the next line of header("Location: http://www.google.com");

someting like this

header("Location: http://www.google.com");
die();